# Unambiguous way to refer to dialects of Standard Italian vs romance languages of Italy?

Tags: word-choice, difference, regional

[*Dialetto*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dialetto/) in the context of Italy has two similar but distinct meanings:

1. different dialects of standard Italian (analogous to RP English vs Mancunian English)
2. other romance languages of Italy (analogous to Spanish vs Catalan)<sup>1</sup>

Are there any **unambiguous**, commonly understood terms for each of these different uses of *dialetto*?

---

<sup>1. In English, *dialect* also has this second definition [historically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dialect#English) - referring to non-prestige/minority languages compared to a prestige one - but it is very rarely used in this context nowadays, and is generally seen as pejorative.</sup>

Comment: Interesting question. Are we sure that it is possibile to unambiguously discern one or the other case for any given dialect/language? The very dictionary article you link to doesn't seem to offer such a distinction, but generally mentions “linguistic systems”. Do you have in mind a criterion based on historical descent? Or mutual intelligibility (or lack thereof)?

Comment: @DaG sorry if my question was unclear - I meant to ask, are there two different terms/phrases in Italian which unambiguously mean "a dialect of standard Italian" and "a romance language of Italy"?

Comment: The question is perfectly clear; it's less clear to me how to distinguish the two objects the terms you are looking for should designate.

Comment: For instance, Maurizio Dardano's _Manualetto di linguistica italiana_ distinguishes Sardinian and Ladin (_idiomi romanzi che si possono considerare vicini al tipo italiano_), while simply calling _dialetti_ all the other ones, which are classified in detail (_dialetti italiani settentrionali_ and _centro-meridionali_, each with further subdivisions). Are you looking for such a distinction?

Comment: Then there is a kind of “vertical” distinction: italiano comune, italiano regionale, dialetto regionale, dialetto.

Comment: @DaG Are you not overthinking the issue? While you are right in saying that it's not easy to classify any given dialect in one of the two categories (are they even mutually exclusive?), I think that the answer should be _no_. Would you not say that the _commonly understood and used_ term for any local language remotely related to Latin on the national territory is referred to as _dialetto_ (even for those dialects that are arguably languages of their own - sardo, friulano ecc...)?

Comment: No, @Easymode44, I'm not sure I'd say so. I'm not especially an expert in “dialects”, and even so I have in my home a book titled _La lingua sarda_ (and the aforementioned quote from Dardano explicitly excludes them from the _dialetti_). So, I'd tentatively say that the two terms are, respectively, _dialetto_ and _lingua_, but for the life of me in many cases I wouldn't be able to say how to classify many idioms, and I agree that those are not necessarily mutually exclusive definitions.

Comment: On second thoughts, @Easymode44, if by “commonly understood and used” we mean, “as used by the man in the street”, I'd probably agree; OP, did you mean this?

Comment: @DaG yes, that is what I meant - layman's term, that is. And yes, I could not tell the difference either!

Comment: @Easymode44: Indeed, probably those who mainly stress the difference between dialect and language – in this context – are linguists (or language buffs like us) and people who are personally involved (Sardinians, Friulians and the like).

Answer (score 4):

If what we are interested in are actually layman's terms for those two – very tricky – concepts, I'd say that, as far as said layman cares, they are just *dialetto* and *lingua* respectively.

Most people would call *dialetto* everything different from Standard Italian as taught in school, others would at least point out that Sardinian and Friulian are actually different *lingue*, still others would claim the status of *lingue* for other idioms as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've usually seen the Romance languages of Italy called either "regional languages" or, in more scientific publications, "Italo-Romance languages" (note however that the second term includes also Standard Italian).

One thing one should note is that the "Italo-Romance languages" is more of a Sprachbund than a linguistic family (indeed the Gallo-Italic languages like Milanese or Piedmontese are arguably more closely related to the other Gallo-Romance languages than to standard Italian). However, the areal features are very strong, and the grouping seems justified.

---

Usually the "dialects" (that is to say, the variation of Standard Italian influenced by regional features) live under the umbrella term of "italiano regionale" or "regional Italian". This is also however mostly reserved to scientific publications (and relatively few of them, at that).

I doubt there are any unambiguous terms that would be understood by the majority of the population.

Comment: I must disagree: in Italian linguistics, as I mentioned in a comment, _dialetto_ is a separate level from _italiano regionale_, with _dialetto regionale_ in between. I agree that these are academic distinctions.

Comment: @DaG I fear that this enters into the discussion of what exactly is a "dialetto", which is fraught with diverging opinions even among professional linguists (and ultimately non well-posed). That's also why I used "live under the umbrella term" rather than "are called" :). In this answer I tried to stay as close as possible as the context of the question, which groups many things that Dardano refers to as "dialetti" in Italo-Romance languages (and rightly so in my opinion: they have separate literatures!)